# How to write a function that prints the lines in data.txt in reverse

Tags: python-3.x, list, file

I am a few weeks into learning python properly and couldn't find out how to split `lines[::-1]` to get the desired result of:

```
Order will return.
Reflect, repent, and reboot
Chaos reigns within.
```

from

```
Chaos reigns within. 
Reflect, repent, and reboot 
Order will return.
```

What I've done so far is print out the 3 sentences in the right order but everything else is wrong.

```
def print_reversed(filename):
    """prints out the lines from the file in reversed order"""
    filename = open(filename) 
    contents = filename.read()   
    lines = contents.splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(lines[::-1])  

print_reversed('data.txt')
```

What I have done so far prints out:

```
['Order will return.', 'Reflect, repent, and reboot ', 'Chaos reigns within. ']
['Order will return.', 'Reflect, repent, and reboot ', 'Chaos reigns within. ']
['Order will return.', 'Reflect, repent, and reboot ', 'Chaos reigns within. ']
```

Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: just remove the for loop and this will enough `print(lines[::-1])  `

Comment: removing the for loop prints ['Order will return.', 'Reflect, repent, and reboot ', 'Chaos reigns within. '] once. Not in the right formatting i want

Comment: `print('\n'.join(lines[::-1]))`

Comment: Thank you that works! However why are we using '\n' when i already have contents = filename.read()   
    lines = contents.splitlines()

Comment: when you split the string will not contain new line because splitlines() consider `\n` as a delimiter